# Find a set of size $m$ consisting of vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that each of its subsets of size $n$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a set of size $m$ consisting of vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that each of its subsets of size $n$ is linearly independent.

Also, what is the maximum $m$ for which this is possible?

So here is my attempt at calculating an upper-bound by induction: $\binom{n+1}{2}$. We can assume $n$ of the vectors are our standard basis. Let the rest of the set be $B$. Now from the standard basis take $\varepsilon_1$, this vector and subset of $B$ of size $n-1$ must together form an independent set. Hence $B$ has size at most $\binom{n}{2}$. Which proves our claim. But I am unable to construct an example with such many vectors or attain a lower upper-bound.

It was pointed out in the comments this proof is wrong, as it doesn't hold for n = 2.

Comment: Consider $\Bbb R^2$ and consider the set of vectors $A=\left\{(x,1)~:~x\in\Bbb R\right\}$.  It should be clear that every pair of vectors in $A$ are linearly independent and it should also be clear that $A$ is uncountably infinite in size.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you construct such an arbitrarily set for any n?

Comment: Yes.  Consider the set $A=\{(1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^{n-1})~:~x\in\Bbb R\}\subseteq \Bbb R^n$.  Any set of $n$ distinct elements of $A$ will be linearly independent.  See [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) on wikipedia for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

An important example is the so called "moment curve" of points $(1,t,t^2,\dots t^{n-1})$. If we choose all of our $m$ points to be on this curve, the claim is that any $n$ of them will be linearly independent.

So see this, suppose not, then there would be a linear functional $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \dots a_nx_n = 0$ satisfied by all of them with out all of the $a_i$'s being $0$. But then the polynomial $a_1+a_2x+a_3x^2+ \dots a_nx^{n-1}$ would be a degree $n-1$ polynomial with $n$ roots, a contradiction.

Of course if you randomly choose $m$ points say uniformly within a ball or from a gaussian distribution they will also have this property you want with probability $1$...